# Border Layout not taking up all available space

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm new to swing, and I suspect the issue has something to do with the BoxLayout. I'm trying to make a series of textfields and labels be one after the other on top of a frame. This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("New Message");
    frame.setSize(100, 100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    frame.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel list = new JPanel();
    list.setLayout(new BoxLayout(list, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    frame.add(list, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    String[] labels = {"To: ", "Cc: ", "Bcc: ", "Subject: "};
    for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        JLabel l = new JLabel(labels[i]);
        JTextField f = new JTextField();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(l, BorderLayout.WEST);
        p.add(f, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        list.add(p);
    }

    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

This is the result:
[image]

What I want is the To, Cc, Bcc and Subject to be all the way on the left and the TextField to take up the rest of the space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few side-notes:

- Start your UI from the EDT by wrapping the UI-initialisation in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`
- It is always a good idea to specify number of columns for a `JTextField`, and both rows and columns for a `JTextArea`
- It is useless to call `setSize()`, if you call `pack()` after. In general, forget about using `setSize()/setLocation/setBounds()` on any Swing component (leave all that to LayoutManager's)

`GridBagLayout` does a pretty good job here. `GroupLayout` can work too.

See this example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Mail {

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("New Message");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel list = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        frame.add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        GridBagConstraints labelGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        labelGBC.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3); // Put some space between elements for nicer look
        labelGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST; // Align left within its cell
        GridBagConstraints fieldGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        fieldGBC.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER; // Last element of the row
        fieldGBC.weightx = 1.0; // Cell takes up all extra horizontal space
        fieldGBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; // Fill the cell horizontally
        fieldGBC.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3); // Put some space between elements for nicer look
        String[] labels = { "To: ", "Cc: ", "Bcc: ", "Subject: " };
        for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
            JLabel l = new JLabel(labels[i]);
            JTextField f = new JTextField(50);
            list.add(l, labelGBC);
            list.add(f, fieldGBC);
        }
        GridBagConstraints taGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        taGBC.gridwidth = 2;
        taGBC.weightx = 1.0; // Cell takes up all extra horizontal space
        taGBC.weighty = 1.0; // Cell takes up all extra vertical space
        taGBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; // Fill cell in both direction
        taGBC.insets = new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3); // Put some space between elements for nicer look
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 80);
        list.add(new JScrollPane(textArea), taGBC);

        frame.pack();

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Mail().initUI();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And the result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `java.awt.FlowLayout` to see one component next to the other.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set a `BorderLayout` on each `JPanel p`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("New Message");
    frame.setSize(100, 100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    frame.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel list = new JPanel();
    list.setLayout(new BoxLayout(list, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    frame.add(list, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    String[] labels = {"To: ", "Cc: ", "Bcc: ", "Subject: "};
    for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        JLabel l = new JLabel(labels[i]);
        JTextField f = new JTextField();
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(l, BorderLayout.WEST);
        p.add(f, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        list.add(p);
    }

    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work and the labels are no longer aligned with the text fields.